# Permission denied for new php files uploaded by ftp user

Tags: php, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

When i try to upload php file using vsftpd to /var/www/ and visit the file from web server i got this error,

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/.../.../public_html/d.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

i tried chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www after that the error got fixed but i have to do the same every time i upload a new file, is there is anyway to fix that for all new files?

Comment: You should be able to set the default permissions for uploaded files by modifying the `vsftpd.conf` try adding `file_open_mode=0777` and 
`local_umask=022`. The first setting states the default permission for uploaded files. Also you could checkout the man page for the configuration file: https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html

Comment: @Cyclonecode i added both to vsftpd.conf and restarted vsftpd but still getting same problem with new files.

Comment: Are you sure you're modifying the correct configuration file?

Comment: ah sorry i edited wrong one, after editing correct file and reloading vsftpd, all new files works fine now. thank you very much!

Comment: @Vedbex do not do what was asked, you've just assigned full read,write,execute permissions to the whole world which has serious security implications.

Comment: @Augwa Thank you but i already know that. its alright since am the only one who have access to server/ftp.

Comment: @Augwa - I didn't mean that he should set complete permission on the file, I meant that he could set default permission by editing the config file.

Comment: @Vedbex you need to update your include_path to contain a path to the directory that you are trying to include. Right not your include path does not have access to search in the location - thus the fatal error.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to apply an ACL to the directory in question.

> This will set the default so new files and folders are given the ACL, this says that the group of www-data will have read,write,execute permissions by default on all files/folders from /var/www recursively

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rwx /var/www
```

> This will set the ACL for existing files and folders, this says that the group of www-data will have read,write,execute from /var/www recursively for existing files and folders

```
sudo setfacl -Rm g:www-data:rwx /var/www
```